# IBM iSeries COnnection String Issue

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am using the .NET IBM iSeries Library. This is the connectionString I am using:

```
 <add connectionString="DataSource=myserver;UserID=xxxx;Password=xxx;ConnectionTimeout=60;AllowUnsupportedChar=true" name="myConnection"/>
```

This works on one laptop and not on another.

I get "Connection String is invalid"

Comment: I wonder if this is similar to my problem I have been having lately. Mine is on a WinForm application.

Comment: same version of IBM iAccess for Windows?  What about Service pack level?

Comment: I had to update it with a Patch. it had the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that reads this you can trap the iDB2InvalidConnectionStringException and look at the "MessageDetails" property to see what part of the connection the system takes offense to.

In my case it did not like the "AllowUnsupportedChar=true" attribute on the connection string because (as Charles mentions above *presumably*) I was using i Access for Windows **v6**, r1. It worked on other machines where we have **v7** installed.